# JQuery mobile list prepend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

trying to prepend my list in jquery mobile but I just can't get the divider to be on top of the most recent item added to the listview.

I've tried prepending the item that's being added but it then switches the divider to the bottom.

```
function loadScanItems(tx, rs) {
    var rowOutput = "";
    var $scanItems = $('#scanItems');
    $scanItems.empty();
    var bubbleCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
        bubbleCount = bubbleCount + 1;
        //rowOutput += renderScan(rs.rows.item(i));
        var row = rs.rows.item(i)
        var now = row.added_on;
        var date = get_date(now);
        rowOutput += '<li data-icon="false"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="webdb.deleteScan(' + row.ID + ');"><div class="ui-grid-b"><div class="ui-block-a" style="width:50%"><h3>Su # ' + row.sunum + '</h3><p> Bin # ' + row.binnum + '</p></div><p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>' + date + '</strong></p><div class="ui-block-b" style="width:20%"></div><div class="ui-block-c" style="width:25%"><br><p>User: ' + row.userid + '</p></div></div></a></li>';
        // rowOutput += '<li><a href="#">' + row.sunum + row.binnum+ "<a href='javascript:void(0);'  onclick='webdb.deleteScan(" + row.ID + ");'>Delete</a></a></li>";
    }
    $scanItems.append('<li data-role="list-divider">Scanned Items <span class="ui-li-count">' + bubbleCount + '</span></li>').listview('refresh');
    $scanItems.append(rowOutput).listview('refresh');
}
```

The code is above with it correctly formatted with the divider on top but the list items being appended to the bottom instead of prepended to the top.

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery has a prepend() as well as append() method: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: Tried prepend but it kept putting it to the bottom, that's why I put this question up

Comment: it is not clear what the problem is? You are emptying the list, then appending items and a divider. As the list is empty, what difference does it make whether you append or prepend? Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L4m55jty/. Can you update it to reproduce your problem and then post the updated fiddle with more description?

Comment: Hi ez thanks, what I can't get is the most recenetly added item on top, it goes to the bottom, iv'e tried prepending and it still doesn't keep the divider on top with the most recent item on top. In your example I'd like su # a4 on top and then a3 a2 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your are building a string with all the scan items. That string already has an order so whether you prepend or append makes no difference. Try this simple change.

Change:

```
rowOutput += '<li data-icon="false">...</li>';
```

to:

```
rowOutput = '<li data-icon="false">...</li>' + rowOutput;
```

This will put your rowOutput string in the correct order before appending to the listview.

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L4m55jty/2/)**